# Comparison of mixed-effects model and a combination of two mixed-effects models

Tags: r, lme4, model-comparison, mean-square-error

I hope this question fits into here because it is not only about a coding problem, but also digs into some theoretical questions concerning linear mixed-effects models. Assume the linear mixed-effects model:

```
model1 <- lmer(RT ~ word_duration + RT_prev + trial + stem + 
                       (1|Subject) + (1|Word), data = df_whole)
```

I can compute its AIC score and use it to compare the model with other models. In my case, I have another model:

```
model2 <- lmer(RT ~ word_duration + RT_prev + trial + form + 
                       (1|Subject) + (1|Word), data = df_subset)
```

The predictions of my `model3` are the minimum of the predictions of model1 and model2 = `min[model1, model2]`. I would like to compare `model3` with `model1` and I know that I could use the mean square error (MSE) for instance. However, the MSE does not take into account that `model3` is a combination of two models and a difference in MSE might not justify the increased complexity. So can I compute a measurement that takes a model's complexity into account such as the AIC in order to compare the models?

Note: `model1` is trained on all the data, `model2` only for a subset. This is done because I assume the items in the subset might be processed differently. Thus, for some items `stem` and for other `form` is the better predictor (as discussed in the literature).

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is *Ensemble Models*.

Comment: @Roland Great! Indeed, I really needed to know this term!